# jQuery Validate plugin addMethod - how to create a numerical form validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to create a jQuery validator using the addMethod. This is all new to me so I'm learning slowly. I have a validator below which is based on a UK mobile phone number. This works fine.

I want to create a new one that is numerical and will only allow a small range of numbers to be accepted in the form. For example numbers 1 to 5 would be accepted, but anything lower or higher isn't accepted.

Also, can it be done that only one number is accepted? i.e. 5.

Any help much appreciated. Like I said, I'm new to this coding, so I'm still finding my way. I have tried numerous searches, but I haven't been able to answer my question.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('mobileUK', function(phone_number, element) {
return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
phone_number.match(/^((0|\+44)7(5|6|7|8|9){1}\d{2}\s?\d{6})$/);
}, 'Please specify a valid mobile number');
```

Comment: It's unclear by how you worded your question, but when I edited your OP, I assumed that you already knew that `addMethod` is part of [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Comment: just an addition @Sparky's answer.  I'm not sure how you found the 'mobileUK' function, but it is a cut down version of the one found in jquery validate additional methods.  Unless you have a specific reason not to use the original, just include additional methods and the 'mobileUK method there, and forget about adding your own method.  an example of this is this forked fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ7Ph/

Answer (score 0):

> **Quote OP**:  "I want to create a new one that is numerical and will only allow a small range of numbers to be accepted in the form. For
>   example numbers 1 to 5 would be accepted, but anything lower or higher
>   isn't accepted."

You do not need to create a new method.  The `.validate()` plugin [can already do this by default](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/range#range).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            fieldname: {
               range: [1, 5]
            }
        },
        messages: { // optional custom message
            fieldname: {
               range: "enter between {0} and {1}"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" />
```

**Working Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/uLSPU/

> **Quote OP:**  "Also, can it be done that only one number is accepted? i.e. 5."

Yes...  http://jsfiddle.net/aTf32/

```
range: [5, 5]
```